# Morphism of varieties from $\mathbb A^1 \to \mathbb A^1 \{0\}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, morphism

> Suppose $f$ is a morphism of varieties from $\mathbb A^1 \to \mathbb A^1 \backslash \{0\}$. What can we say about $f$ ?

I am unable to deduce much. I know that $f$ will induce a $k$ algebra map $k[x] \to k[x]$ by pulling back the regular functions. What more can be said about $f$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you aware that $\mathbb A^1\backslash \{ 0 \}$ is also affine? It is isomorphic to $V(xy - 1) \subset \mathbb A^2$ via the mapping $x \mapsto (x, 1/x)$. The coordinate ring of $V(xy - 1) \subset \mathbb A^2$ is
$$ k[x,y]/(xy - 1) \cong k[x,x^{-1}].$$

Therefore, following your line of reasoning, your geometric problem reduces to the algebraic problem of finding $k$-algebra morphisms from $k[x,x^{-1}] $ to $k[x]$. I'll leave this to you.

---

Alternatively, extend your morphism $\mathbb A^1 \to \mathbb A^1 \backslash \{ 0 \}$ to a morphism $\mathbb A^1 \to \mathbb A^1$ by composing with the inclusion $\mathbb A^1 \backslash \{ 0 \} \hookrightarrow \mathbb A^1$. The composition $\mathbb A^1 \to \mathbb A^1$ must be given by $x \mapsto f(x)$ for some polynomial $f(x) \in k[x]$. Assuming $k$ is algebraically closed, is it possible for the image of this map to avoid $0$ if $f(x)$ is a non-constant polynomial?

Comment: By $2$nd argument i can see that map has to be zero map. But why is there no non constant $k-$ algebra map from $k[x,x^{-1} ] \to k[x]$ ? Probably because there is no non constant invertible element in RHS?

Comment: This map has to be a constant, non-zero map. There are $k$-algebra maps from $k[x,x^{-1}]$ to $k[x]$. You just need to find classify them. Hint: Show that the image of $x$ under this $k$-algebra map must be a unit in $k[x]$.

Comment: Yeah basically $x$ and $x^{-1}$ will go to inverse of each other and hence map has to be constant map?

Comment: Yes. The only units in $k[x]$ are the non-zero constants.

Comment: Yeah,thanks a lot!